# Can't find what is wrong with the code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I Have this code, and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. It does not return any error but field Date_Returned is not getting updated. Please help.

```
Private Sub txtbxret_Click()
Dim query As String
query = "UPDATE Rent SET Date_Returned = '" & Date & "' WHERE Date_Rent = " & txtrented.Value & " AND Customer_ID = " & txtbxcustID.Value & " AND Movie_ID = " & txtbxmovID.Value
DoCmd.RunSQL (query)


End Sub
```

I've double and triple checked all the field names and thay are ok by the way...

Comment: Hint: bobby-tables (quotes in where), or maybe the date format you get with `&`?

Comment: what could be wrong with date format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use proper formatting of string expressions of date values in SQL:

```
query = "UPDATE Rent SET Date_Returned = Date() WHERE Date_Rent = #" & Format(txtrented.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND Customer_ID = " & txtbxcustID.Value & " AND Movie_ID = " & txtbxmovID.Value
```

Comment: I love you! Seriously, give me your address and I'm sending you 6-pack of beer right now.

Comment: Let's just make those beers virtual. Thanks!